# Connection SSH with library phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I need your support for the next problematic , they let me develop a PHP page that connects by SSH to log 'm taking the library phpseclib and works well , the problem is now I need to connect to a computer from the first since no you can access it directly , do you know that command perform this action ? Please I need it soon.

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2(x.x.x.x',22);
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'evergreen')) 
{
  exit('Login Failed');
}

 else
 {


 $ssh1= $ssh->exec('ssh oracle01:oracle@10.1.0.84');
 echo $ssh1;
}
```

Comment: Enable error reporting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/3885509

Comment: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). Tha second connection don't work.

Comment: there are many form to this comant ssh oracle:oracle01@10.1.0.84? or put the gateway in the login?

Comment: Try this but the problem continuos :  $ssh->exec('ssh oracle@x.x.x.x');  $ssh->exec('pass');

Comment: I'd use public key auth. Put a private key in the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file and then put the public key in 10.1.0.84's authorized_keys file. Also, this question would probably be better posted on superuser.com. You're question is, ultimately, about the SSH CLI command - not about programming.